# Bulk Mail Sending Through AWS SES

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon AWS SES to send my email campaigns. I have around 35,000 subscribers on my list. At present I am using a code something similar to the following.

```
for (Entry<Integer, String> emailEntry : email_ids.entrySet()) {
        MimeMessage msg = getMimeMessage(emailEntry.getKey(), emailEntry.getValue());
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                msg.writeTo(outputStream);
        RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));

        ses.sendRawEmail(new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage));
    }
```

This way I was able to send email to all my subscribers the way I wanted. But there was a huge bill accounting to Data transfer. Each MimeMessage is of 150Kb in size and sending it to 35,000 subscribers resulted in 5.5 GB of data transfer.

So I decided to use BulkTemplateEmail in my application, to create the template once and send it to 35,000 emails. This way the email has to be send to SES only once and there will be significant gain in terms of data transfer.

Can anyone provide me a sample to do this via Java AWS SDK? I want to add List-Unsubscribe header on each Destination. This is where I am actually stuck. Couldn't find any methods to add custom email headers for each Destination. Is this possible with BulkTemplateEmail?

Any info is highly appreciated.

Comment: AWS Data-In is free. Data-Out is charged for. Switching to bulk will not change Data-Out.

Comment: @JohnHanley Do they charge data for the email sent from SES to destinations? I am sure that data is charged for emails we are sending. But don't know where they are charging. In pricing it is written EC2 to SES is not charged. But we're charged at the rate of EC2 to Internet.

Comment: I actually don't know the answer. However, it does not matter - you are charged for Data-Out. The pricing page lists $0.12 per GB of attachments. https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/

Comment: Yes we are charged for data out only. We are not sending out any attachments. This month we have reached 60 GB after sending 1 million email. That's something to look out.

Comment: You must be including attachments otherwise you would be sending blank emails. The attachment for billing purposes is everything in the body of the email. When you send MIME emails, the attachments, pictures, etc. are base64 encoded in the body of the email message. TIP: redesign your emails so that your images are not embedded in your emails and instead come from a web server (or CloudFront / S3). This will reduce your email message size. With CloudFront, the first 50 GB is free for the first year. CloudFront pricing is region specific but is a lot cheaper than SES in most regions.

Comment: I think that helped. My email contains one 2-4 images located on my server.  So I think for each open we receive the images are fetched from server. That solves the mystery. Thanks for the help. I didn't see that coming. So using BulkTemplateEmail is not going to solve my issue. We are operating only in US and in a particular city only. Again thanks for the info. You should post this an answer, so that I can mark it as solved. Include my scenario also in your answer. I am fetching images from EC2-instance and hence the higher cost:-)

Comment: Look for an email service provider, like [Sparkpost](https://sparkpost.com) (Disclaimer: I work for Sparkpost.) The first 100k emails per month are free. Plus you probably don't have to reinvent the wheel and will probably get better delivery rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending emails using SES, Amazon charges for data transfer out. The current price is $0.12 per GB. For large volumes of emails this can result in serious charges.

[Amazon SES pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/)

For embedded images, attachments, etc. another solution is to use links instead of embedded objects. This way you can mitigate and reduce data transfers fees. This can have a moderate to high impact for email campaigns where a lot of emails are never opened, thereby saving on the data transfer charges.

If your links reference files on your EC2 instances, remember that you will still be charged for Data-Out from your EC2 instances. S3 will provide a lower cost.

Comment: We used links for images in our emails. But the links where pointing to images on our EC2 instance. That is what caused the high data transfer fees.Whenever image is fetched by the email clients, EC2 instance sends out data to the internet.